# React SetState Updation time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

how much time react will take to update the data in SetState.
For Example if i am updating one data using SetState in react. what is expected time period for  updation(SetState) functionality.

Comment: Are you trying to benchmark something?  Or are you trying to figure out how to work with multiple setStates in your program?

Comment: It's guaranteed to be updated on the subsequent render. How long it takes depends on the complexity of the state and the speed of the machine its running on, but unless you're performance tuning React itself it's generally not something you need to worry about.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Absolutely correct. I am trying to find out what is the time interval for calling the usestate or usestate for a smooth update. I try to update the 10 data per second. But usestate taking too much time interval for updating state. Sometimes it goes beyond 2 minutes.

Comment: @ray hatfield. I want to improve my application performance so I need to check the time interval for the update state variable.  Because I am receiving more than 10 data per second. If I am updating directly with the flow of data the updating state variable takes more than 2 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by "updating state variable takes more than 2 minutes"? It takes 2 minutes to re-render your view after setState? It's possible it takes longer than 100ms to render and you're updating more frequently than that so it never catches up, but if that's the case you're asking the wrong question.